# MySQL Join Over 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

### The Situation

We have these 5 different MySQL tables:

Table club

```
Id | ClubName | CityId
---+----------+--------
1  | Test     | 1
```

Table city

```
Id | CityName | CountryId
---+----------+-----------
1  | London   | 1
```

Table country

```
Id | CountryName
---+------------
1  | UK
```

Table Genre

```
Id | GenreName
---+-----------
1  | Rock
2  | Classic
3  | Techno
```

Table club2genre

```
ClubId | GenreId
-------+--------
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
```

### What is expected

The expected result would be this:

```
ClubId | Club | City   | Country | Music
-------+------+--------+---------+---------------------
1      | Test | London | UK      | Rock,Classic,Techno
```

### What I've tried

Using the following query

```sql
SELECT
    club.Id AS ClubId,
    club.ClubName AS Club,
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre.GenreName) as Music
FROM
    club
INNER JOIN club2genre
    ON club2genre.clubid = club.id
INNER JOIN genre
    ON genre.id = club2genre.genreid
GROUP BY 
    club.Id;
```

I managed to get the following result:

```
ClubId | Club | Music
-------+------+-------------------
1      | Test | Rock,Classic,Techno
```

However I've now been trying for hours to somehow link the City and Country to the result but stuff like this:

```sql
SELECT
    club.Id,
    club.ClubName AS Name,
    city.CityName AS City,
    country.CountryName AS Country,
    CONCAT(genre.GenreName) as Music
FROM
    club, city, country
INNER JOIN club2genre
    ON club2genre.clubid = club.id
INNER JOIN genre
    ON genre.id = club2genre.genreid
WHERE
    club.CityId = city.Id AND city.CountryId = country.Id;
```

doesn't work and MySQL just throws errors like `ERROR: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'club.id' in 'on clause'`. Then again it this point I'm more guessing than actually knowing what I'm doing. I assume I'd have to throw even more joins in there?
I'm not that familiar with MySQL and it's been ages since I touched SQL in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of mixing the join syntax via `club, city, country INNER JOIN`, just use a proper `JOIN` statement per table that isn't `club`. Make sure to [brush up on the differences between left/right/inner/etc joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Explicit JOIN chains are evaluated before comma separated items. This means the ON clause doesn't know about the club table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing explicit and implicit join syntax.Use explicit only.

Also you should properly GROUP BY all columns that are in SELECT clause without aggregate function

That gives:

```
SELECT
    club.Id,
    club.ClubName AS Name,
    city.CityName AS City,
    country.CountryName AS Country,
    CONCAT(genre.GenreName) as Music
FROM
    club
INNER JOIN city
    ON club.CityId= city.id
INNER JOIN country
    ON country.Id= city.CountryId
INNER JOIN club2genre
    ON club2genre.clubid = club.id
INNER JOIN genre
    ON genre.id = club2genre.genreid
GROUP BY 
    club.Id, club.ClubName, city.CityName, country.CountryName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use INNER JOINS instead of cross joins which the comas repsresetnt

```
SELECT
    club.Id,
    club.ClubName AS Name,
    MIN(city.CityName) AS City,
    MIN(country.CountryName) AS Country,
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre.GenreName) as Music
FROM
    club
    INNER JOIN city ON club.CityId = city.Id
    INNER JOIN  country ON city.CountryId = country.Id
INNER JOIN club2genre
    ON club2genre.clubid = club.id
INNER JOIN genre
    ON genre.id = club2genre.genreid
GROUP BY 
    club.Id,club.ClubName
```